# Google Calendar notifications via Growl for Windows or native toast notificaitons

Tags: windows-8, google-calendar, growl

Is there a way to hook up google calendar notifications with [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx), or so that it displays notifications via Windows' native toast messaging system?